Issue with Using Regex on Redis FT.SEARCH Results in Grafana
I am new to Redis and am currently working on a project where we store sensor data in Redis. We use the FT.SEARCH command to retrieve sensor details. Among the retrieved details, I am particularly interested in extracting only the id values to use as variables for further queries.
Below is the query I am using:
FT.SEARCH :farms.cache.DeviceCacheModel:index "@farm:[14 14] @type:{exhaust}" RETURN 1 id LIMIT 0 200

The output of this query looks like this (truncated for brevity):
`403
:farms.cache.DeviceCacheModel:01J04B7PD1YTRDH02FWPRTYNQ6
id
D895
:farms.cache.DeviceCacheModel:01J04B7NN4N0QCPE3X6AAZTJ27
D869
:farms.cache.DeviceCacheModel:01J04B7PF6B4169W6SVKF18AGS
D359
`
From the results, I want to extract only the id values (D895, D869, D359, etc.).
I tried using regex patterns to achieve this. For example:

 "id":"([^"]+)"
    \b(D\d+)\b


While these regex patterns work perfectly in tools like regex101 or similar online regex testers, they do not yield any results when applied in Grafana. I suspect there might be an issue with how the regex is interpreted or applied in Grafana in the context of Redis FT.SEARCH results.
My Questions:

Am I missing something in my query or regex usage that is causing the issue in Grafana?
Is there a specific way Grafana handles regex with Redis results that I need to be aware of?
Alternatively, is there a better approach to directly extract the id values from the FT.SEARCH results?

I appreciate any guidance or suggestions. Thank you in advance for your help!

It does not support regex.

Thanks for the clarification @WiktorStribiżew, is there any document available online for this so that i can get more clarity on this

I googled that within  a minute, here - https://redis.io/docs/latest/develop/interact/search-and-query/query/

Grafana supports regex, but in rather limited capacity. If result you tried to show is multiple items, and each contains a single id - it might work: tinker with regex more and you'll get there. If result is a single item and you want to extract multiple ids from it - it won't work. No clue how Grafana integrates with redis, so answer for that big if you'll need to find yourself.

I suspect you have a formatting error in your question. What do the results really look like?
You may find that you get better results by using the FT.AGGREGATE command which lets you manipulate your output in useful ways
